# Transparent transition from asmx webservice to wcf service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, asmx

I'm working on a project where I'm replacing an asmx webservice with a wcf service.  However, during a transition period, I'd like to have both work for our customers.

So I've achieved this somewhat, however I've run into a wall during some testing.  I'm getting the following message:

> Test method IntegrationTests.StrictMatchTests.StrictProviderPass threw exception:  System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: The message with Action 'https://secure.mydomain.net/core/myMethod' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None)..

I have an asmx file exposed, and I can consume it as a traditional web service.  However, they don't seem to be compatible with the older service.  If I consume the new service, it works just fine.  But I would like this initial transition to be transparent to the end user, and gradually have them consume the wcf service over time.

Anyone tackle something like this before?  If so, can you please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to show the server-side configuration. The two technologies are not incompatible, per se. Look at the actual exception message (including any Inner exceptions), figure out what it's complaining about, and fix it.

Comment: Also, why do you need to have "both"? It's just a change of URL, isn't it?

Comment: John - thanks for the reply.  The end user is used to going to a url like this:  https://my.website.com/app/default.asmx.  I would like that url to still work on the new web service, just so for a period of time our end user will not be impacted.  At the same time, we want the new url "https://my.website/com/app/service.svc" to work as well, so we can notify our end users to move towards that.  It's very possible I'm going about this in the wrong way, web development is still somewhat new to me.

Comment: "used to going to a URL" - really? It's really difficult to give them a different URL? What would you have done if the ASMX service had moved to a different server?

Comment: Hi John, for me, it's all minimal customer impact.  Lets just say, we have difficult customers and the more transparent we can make this move, the better.  We actually are moving servers, we're migrating our service to run on Windows Azure.  -- I haven't had a chance to dig into the exception anymore, but plan on doing that sometime in the next day or two.  Hopefully there is an inner exception that is a bit more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue.  I found there was a difference between the two data contracts.  One of the properties in the data contract had a case difference.  Corrected this resolved the issue.  I figured this out by getting a copy of the generated service reference for the old service and the new service.  I compared the two references side by side and noticed the case difference.

John - thanks for your suggestions above.

Comment: Thanks for updating us with the resolution. +1 for that.